# read dynamic xml reader for windows phone?

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

In my XML file chapters tag has more chapter tag.i need to display chapters name in first page.when i click chapter in the list box next page will display the titles in the chapter.then click the title next page will display the content.i tried static page.it will run clearly.but i had problem in dynamic page navigation.`

```
<chapter>
  <title>
    <![CDATA[Decorating Tips]]>
  </title>
  <position>1</position>
  <paragraphs>
    <paragraph>
      <title>To Determine Gender or Not</title>
      <position>1</position>
      <text>
        <![CDATA[<meta name="viewport" content="width=320" /><p style="text-align: justify;">With the creation of ultrasounds,<br/>many decision, you can move forward.</p>]]>
      </text>
    </paragraph>
    <paragraph>
      <title>Neutral, Please</title>
      <position>2</position>
      <text>
        <![CDATA[<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,height=device-height' /><p style="text-align: just></p>]]>
      </text>
    </paragraph>
    <paragraph>
      <title>Noah&#8217;s Ark</title>
          </chapter>
<chapter>
  <title>
    <![CDATA[The Necessities]]>
  </title>
  <position>2</position>
  <paragraphs>
    <paragraph>
      <title>Paint</title>
      <position>1</position>
      <text>
        <![CDATA[<p style="text-align: justify;">Sne are shades of yellow,&nbsp; green, beige  of.</p>]]>
      </text>
    </paragraph>
    <paragraph>
      <title>Wall Paper and Bedding</title>
      <position>2</position>
      <text>
        <![CDATA[<p style="text-align: justifinundated with themes. And&nbsp; since the or baby.</p>]]>
      </text>
    </paragraph>          
  </paragraphs>
</chapter>
<chapter>
  <title>
    <![CDATA[Other Fun Ways to Decorate]]>
  </title>
  <position>3</position>
  <paragraphs>
    <paragraph>
      <title>Twinkle Lights Around the Perimeter</title>
      <position>1</position>
      <text>
        <![CDATA[<p style="text-align: justify;">during the day.<br /></p>]]>
      </text>
    </paragraph>
    <paragraph>
      <title>Growth Chart</title>
      <position>2</position>
      <text>
        <![CDATA[<p style="text-align: justify;">Ysomeday &ndash; and the date.</p>]]>
      </text>
    </paragraph>
          </paragraphs>
</chapter>
</chaptesr>`
```

Comment: 1 suggestion, better read the same XML file in two pages(i.e in chapter page and title page)?!

Comment: when i click chapters list corresponding titles want to display.then after click titles description display in another page.please help me.

Comment: its simple I reckon, use xmlreader to read all the chapters first and display in your page. Then after the user click the chapter, use navigation technique to pass the chapter value to the next page. There read the same xml file but look for only the chapter you want e.g reader.Name.equals(chapter name) Its not a solution. Its a different logic thats it! to pass chapter value `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml?msg=" + string_chapter, UriKind.Relative));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you already create class hierarchy that describe chapters-paragraphs-paragraph structure.

On first page bind `DataContext` to `Chapters collection` to display each chapter.

When user clicks on some chapter, set `SelectedChapter` property on `ViewModel` to clicked `Chapter` object. Then navigate to second page, where `DataContext` is binded to `SelectedChapter` property to display each paragraph.

When user clicks on some paragraph, set `SelectedParagraph` property on `ViewModel` to clicked `Paragraph` object, and so on...