# xml parsing in windows phone?

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

I used below code:

```
    var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("chapter")
                   select new CountryData
                   {
                       Title = (string)query.Element("title"),
                       data1 = from pharagraph in loadedData.Descendants("pharagraph")
                               select new CountryData
                               {
                                   Title1=(string)pharagraph.Element("title"),
                                   Des = (string)pharagraph.Element("text"),
                                   Position = (int)pharagraph.Element("position"),
                               }
                   };
        countryList = data.ToList();
```

i had error when displaying Title1 value.how to display inner title tag in XML reader.my xml file look like:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431276/read-dynamic-xml-reader-for-windows-phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably select `pharagraph` not from `loadedData`:

```
data1 = from pharagraph in loadedData.Descendants("pharagraph")
```

But from `pharagraphs` element (or something like that depending on your xml):

```
data1 = from pharagraph in (query.Element("pharagraphs")).Descendants("pharagraph")
```

Full-code:

```
var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("chapter")
               select new CountryData
               {
                   Title = (string)query.Element("title"),
                   data1 = (from pharagraph in (query.Element("pharagraphs")).Descendants("pharagraph")
                           select new CountryData
                           {
                               Title1=(string)pharagraph.Element("title"),
                               Des = (string)pharagraph.Element("text"),
                               Position = (int)pharagraph.Element("position"),
                           }).ToList()
               };
    countryList = data.ToList();
```

Comment: but i had error when using the above code.please explain.please give some sample code to parse XML data like above.

Comment: Updated my answer. Cast to `string` was unwanted. Also, I added `ToList()`. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much.when i bind the Title1 value into text block i had error.sorry am new to windows phone.i don't have guide in my place.

Comment: how to parse inner title tag to into into textblock.

Comment: inner `title` is a list. You can use `ItemsControl` inside each item `DataTemplate` to show all inner titles. But this is another question...

Comment: sorry for repeating my question.my XML look like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431276/read-dynamic-xml-reader-for-windows-phone.my first page i have to display the chapter title.next page will display the paragraph title.when i click the paragraph title third page will display the description.